# Emgu CV 3.1.0 - error: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.MatInvoke' threw an exception. help me out

Tags: opencv, emgucv

imgOriginal = New Mat(ofdOpenFile.FileName, LoadImageType.Color)

this is where exception throw

Comment: Found it my self!! i tried x86 directories instead of x64..it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**
Your should set project build properties to x86 or x64 platform target.
If cvextern.dll - 32bit to platform target: x86
If cvextern.dll - 64bit to platform target: x64

**Second solution:**
After/or (you may configure build process) build project create two folder: x86 include 32bit version cvextern.dll and x64 folder including 64bit version cvextern.dll in your output (bin\Debug or something) folder. Then your should change project build properties to Any CPU.